# Setting permissions in ubuntu to prevent access

Tags: permissions

I have a doubt regarding ubuntu permissions. I am embedding a flash file test.swf inside another php file say test.php and uploaded to my server(www.example.com/test.html)

I need to protect test.swf from unauthorized read.So I changed the permission to 0440(only owner and group can read). I changed the permission of test.php to 0644(owner,group and other) so that everyone can read. Is it possible to view my test.swf inside test.php file at the same time not accessible for those accessing directly.

Answer (score 0):

If `test.swf` (or `test.php`) is accessed through the local filesystem, the accessor's `UID` and `GID` along with the file's (and directory's) permissions govern access.

If `test.swf` is requested via the web server, then it's rules (and the `UID` and `GID` of its user) apply.

Did I misunderstand? Who is the "directly accessing unauthorized reader"?